Read and write permissions inside any folder selected by the user in the phone's storage without the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
Is there a way to let users select a folder using a file picker package in Flutter and provide the app with read and write access to that folder?
I previously used the 'Manage External Storage' permission as I couldn't find any other solution, but the Play Store imposes strict restrictions on this permission. I've come across the Storage Access Framework (SAF) and wonder if it could be a viable alternative. Can SAF or any other framework handle this requirement?
Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Yes, I think SAF would be most suitable for your requirements (Reading and Writing to a folder), and also it is Play Store compliant.

Simply you can use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let users select specific folder and then get the URI of that folder, then you can read and write to files in that particular folder.

@VanshPatel Can you provide the link to packages which i could use.

This pub.dev link and Github Link would help.


Is there a way to let users select a folder using a file picker
package in Flutter and provide the app with read and write access to
that folder?

No. User can select folder to get or write data from/to the folder but the app won't get read and write access. If user's required to select folder every time, you don't need any permission
If you need to read/write data from/to external storage without user action, you can use Scoped Storage but app's access will be limited to app specific external storage folder.

Hey user I want to access folders other than app specific external storage folder, Once the users selects a folder i am saving that storage path and then the app should be able to read and write into that folder whenever needed.

@AdarshTiwari It's not possible without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. And Google play wont let you publish the app if you cant justify that permission. What you're looking for doesn't exist in Android. Users can't "choose" a folder and grant read/write access to the app. There's no such feature
